# create new col based on transformation on some group based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there a more performant way to do something like the following after group by?

For each `group`, I'd like to get the max `value` for which `time` is <= 3

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


d = dict(group=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], times=[0,1,2,3,4]*3, values=np.random.rand(15))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

# e.g.:

    group  times    values
0       1      0  0.277623
1       1      1  0.227311
2       1      2  0.798941
3       1      3  0.861006
4       1      4  0.486385
5       2      0  0.543527
6       2      1  0.347159
7       2      2  0.138165
8       2      3  0.152132
9       2      4  0.402830
10      3      0  0.688038
11      3      1  0.450904
12      3      2  0.351267
13      3      3  0.195594
14      3      4  0.834823
```

The following seems to work, but is a little slow and not very concise:

```
for label, group in df.groupby(['group']):
    rows = group.index
    df.loc[rows,'new_value'] = group.loc[group.time <= 3, 'values'].max()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you can use `where` before grouping. For better performance, use `transform`:

```
df['new_value'] = df['values'].where(df.times < 3).groupby(df.group).transform('max')    
df

    group  times    values  new_value
0       1      0  0.271137   0.751412
1       1      1  0.262456   0.751412
2       1      2  0.751412   0.751412
3       1      3  0.364099   0.751412
4       1      4  0.462447   0.751412
5       2      0  0.022403   0.792396
6       2      1  0.792396   0.792396
7       2      2  0.181434   0.792396
8       2      3  0.106931   0.792396
9       2      4  0.226425   0.792396
10      3      0  0.425845   0.535085
11      3      1  0.527567   0.535085
12      3      2  0.535085   0.535085
13      3      3  0.194340   0.535085
14      3      4  0.958947   0.535085
```

This is exactly what your current code returns.

---

`where` ensures we do not consider values for times > 3, because `max` ignores NaNs. The `groupby` is computed on this intermediate result.

```
df['values'].where(df.times <= 3)

0     0.271137
1     0.262456
2     0.751412
3     0.364099
4          NaN
5     0.022403
6     0.792396
7     0.181434
8     0.106931
9          NaN
10    0.425845
11    0.527567
12    0.535085
13    0.194340
14         NaN
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: cool.  Any idea why it fails when grouping by multiple columns?  The real data set has three groupings before this operation, and I can't seem to get the groupby syntax posted here to work on multiple columns...

Comment: @anon01 Your syntax will be slightly different. Use `.groupby([df['col1'], df['col2'], ...])` specifying each column as a separate element in the list that you pass to `groupby`..